# How to reset or clear items in RecyclerView upon backstack navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments: Fragment A contains a recyclerview of 5 article items and Fragment B contains the webview of the selected article in Fragment A.

Upon going back from Fragment B to A, my items in the recyclerview in Fragment A doubled. So basically, Fragment A is now showing duplicate items which are not what I want.

I tried to override the `onResume` method in Fragment A like this but no luck:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        arrayArticles.clear()
        val articlesAdapter = TipsRecyclerAdapter(arrayArticles, this)
        binding.tipsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.tipsRecyclerView.adapter = articlesAdapter
}
```

PS: I am using the navigation component to navigate between fragments.

Comment: The code you provided should not double the items . there is some other culprit so add whole the code with question(u can omit the useless part ) .. You should not be setting adapter in `onResume` better do it inside `onViewCreated()` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @ADM, I moved my adapter setup to `onViewCreated()`. I found a simple fix that I just added at `onCreateView()`:

```
if(arrayArticles.size == 0){
   arrayArticles.add(article1)
   arrayArticles.add(article2)
   ...
}
...
```

then on `onViewCreated()`:

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
val articlesAdapter = TipsRecyclerAdapter(arrayArticles, this)
binding.tipsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
binding.tipsRecyclerView.adapter = articlesAdapter
```

Checking the arraylist size is necessary because I think the adding of articles into the arraylist is executed again upon back navigation